# platform method missing warning in creating a HTTP Request in Google AppEngine JAVA SDK1.9.50

Tags: java, http, google-app-engine

I am making a URL request using the following JAVA code

```
URL urlObj = new URL( urlStr );
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)urlObj.openConnection();
httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");

int statusCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
if ( statusCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK ) {
    logger.severe( "Error in opening url:" + urlStr );
    return;
}

bufferReader = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader( httpConn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8" ) );
String line = null;
while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
        logger.info( line );
}
```

It run on Google App Engine works without any problem at appengine sdk 1.9.49. 
But when I upgrade to 1.9.50 it return the following warning

```
[INFO] 3月 11, 2017 12:04:51 下午 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil supportsUnsafeByteBufferOperations
[INFO] 警告: platform method missing - proto runtime falling back to safer methods: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.misc")
[INFO] 3月 11, 2017 12:04:51 下午 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil.supportsUnsafeArrayOperations
[INFO] 警告: platform method missing - proto runtime falling back to safer methods: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.misc")
[INFO] 3月 11, 2017 12:04:51 下午 com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil.supportsUnsafeCopyMemory
[INFO] 警告: copyMemory is missing from platform - proto runtime falling back to safer methods.
```

What action do I need to take or just ignore it? Thx

Comment: Happens on me in both version 49 and 50. And it shows 404 Error not found in the response.

Answer (score 0):

The current version is [1.9.52](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download). You should check whether the issue persists in 1.9.52, and if it does, you should file a [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) report for us to take a look at. You've noticed what is called a *regression* in software, a change to functionality between version releases where something that previously worked no longer works.